# First Fit Decreasing Algorithm on CVRP in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, heuristics

I am using the FFD Algorithm in Optaplanner as a construction heuristic for my  CVRP problem. I thought I understood the FFD-Alg from bin picking, but I don't understand the logic behind it when applied in OP on CVRP. So my thought was, it focuses on the demands (Sort cities in decreasing order, starting with the highest demand). To proof my assumption, I fixed the city coordinates to only one location, so the distance to the depot of all cities is the same. Then I changed the demands from big to small. But it doesn't take the cities in decrasing order in the result file.

The Input is: City 1: Demand 16, City 2: Demand 12, City 3: Demand 8, City 4: Demand 4, 
City 5: Demand 2.

3 Vehicles with a capacity of 40 per vehicle.

What I thougt: V1<-[C1,C2,C3,C4], V2<-[C5]
What happened: V1<-[C5,C4,C3,C2], V2<-[C1]

Could anyone please explain me the theory of this? Also, I would like to know what happens the other way around, same capacities, but different locations per customer. I tried this too, but it also doesn't sort the cities beginning with the farthest one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(braindump)

Unlike with non-VRP problems, the choice of "difficulty comparison" to determine the "Decreasing Difficulty" of "First Fit Decreasing", isn't always clear. I've done experiments with several forms - such as based on distance to depot, angle to depot, latitude, etc. You can find all those forms of difficulty comperators in the examples, usually TSP.

One common pitfall is to tweak the comperator before enabling Nearby Selection: tweak Nearby Selection first. If you're dealing with large datasets, an "angle to depo" comparator will behave much better, just because Nearby Selection and/or Paritioned Search aren't active yet. In any case, as always: you need to be using [optaplanner-benchmark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg) for this sort of work.

This being said, on a *pure* TSP use case, the First Fit Decreasing algorithm has worse results than the **Nearest Neighbor** algorithm (which is another construction heuristics for which we have limited support atm). Both require Local Search to improve further, of course. However, translating the Nearest Neighbor algorithm to VRP is difficult/ambiguous (to say the least): I was/am working on such a translation and I am calling it the **Bouy** algorithm (look for a class in the vrp example that starts with Bouy). It works, but it doesn't combine well with Nearby Selection yet IIRC.

Oh, and there's also the **Clarke and Wright savings** algorithm, which is great on small pure CVRP cases. But suffers from BigO (= scaling) problems on bigger datasets and it too becomes difficult/ambiguous when other constraints are added (such as time windows, skill req, lunch breaks, ...).

Long story short: **the jury's still out on what's the best construction heuristic for real-world, advanced VRP cases.** optaplanner-benchmark will help us there. This despite all the academic papers talking about their perfect CH for a simple form of VRP on small datasets...

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes I wondered that there are no classical academical Heuristics implemented, but now it became more clear.